# Limit filesize of a filestream?

Tags: c++, stl

My application currently logs in a very simple way:

```
void Log::create( const std::string& path, bool append )
{
    if(append)
    m_log.open(path.c_str(),std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app);
    else
        m_log.open(path.c_str(),std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc);
}

std::ofstream& Log::get()
{
    return m_log;
}

void Log::write( const std::string& what )
{
    get() << "[" << TimeOfDay::getDate() << "] ";
    get() << what << std::endl;
}

void Log::write( const std::string& where, const std::string& what )
{
    get() << "[" << TimeOfDay::getDate() << "] ";
    get() << "[" << where << "] " << what << std::endl;
}

std::ofstream& Log::write()
{
    get() << "[" << TimeOfDay::getDate() << "] ";
    return get();
}

std::ofstream Log::m_log;
```

This application runs on a server. Now, if the log exceeds a certain file size, I want to stop logging.

Is there a way to do this without boost or other libraries?

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just keep track of the number of lines written by incrementing a counter within the various `write()` overloads? Boost.Filesystem has the [`file_size`](http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#file_size) function that does what you want. MSVC 2013 ships with a `<filesystem>` implementation that is based on Boost so it should offer the same functionality, if you're using that compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a filtering stream buffer which is set up to write a file but stops writing if it has written more than a specified amount of data. Something like this:

```
class limitbuf
    : public std::streambuf {
    std::streambuf* sbuf;
    size_t          size;
    size_t          limit;
    char            buffer[1024];
public:
    limitbuf(std::streambuf* sbuf, size_t limit)
        : sbuf(sbuf), limit(limit), size(0)
    {
        this->setp(buffer, buffer + 1023);
    }
    int overflow(int c) {
        if (c != std::char_traits<char>::eof()) {
            this->pptr() = std::char_traits<char>::to_char_type(c);
            this->pbump(1);
        }
        return this->sync() == 0
            ? std::char_traits<char>::not_eof(c)
            : std::char_traits<char>::eof();
    }
    int sync() {
        if (this->size < limit) {
             this->size += this->sbuf->sputn(this->pbase(),
                 std::min(
                     size_t(this->pptr() - this->pbase()),
                     this->limit - this->size)
                 );
             this->sbuf->pubsync();
        }
        this->setp(this->pbase(), this->epptr());
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Just install this stream buffer as a filter to your log file and it should be limiting to some suitable size:

```
std::ofstream out("some.log", 16384);
limitbuf      sbuf(out.rdbuf());
std::ostream  log(&sbuf);
```

The basic idea of this stream buffer is fairly simple: data is buffer internally and written upon a buffer overflow or upon a flush:

- When the buffer set up with `setp()` overflows the stream calls `overflow(c)` with the next character to be written (or, potentially, with `std::char_traits<char>::eof()`). Since te stream buffer was told about a buffer one character smaller than actually available, the overflowing character is added to the buffer and the overall buffer is flushed.
- When the buffer is flushed (e.g. by using `std::endl` on the `std::ostream` writing to this buffer) the function `sync()` ends up being called. Its just is to write the characters currently buffered. The code simply sees if there is still space for anything to be written and writes the character if there is space available. The `size` member maintains how many characters are written and `limit` is set up to indicate how much data is to be written.

If the stream buffer should do more than just limit the output, it may be necessary to modify the logic of what is happening if there is no more space. For example, if there are left-over characters which can't be written the stream buffer could decide to open a new file (and possibly move other files).

Comment: I also need to be able to move the log if it is full and then a new log would be created in its place.

Comment: @Milo: you didn't mention this requirement before... Anyway: the technique is roughly the same. You would probably keep a `std::filebuf` in the stream buffer used for logging and take a base name as configuration. In `sync()` you'd then not just stop writing but rather close the existing file rename the existing logs, possibly up to a limit, and open a new file and write to that.

Comment: int g = get().tellp();

Comment: @Milo: 1. if you want, you can obviously implement seeking on stream buffers although I consider doing so mostly a useless exercise. 2. why would you want to find the write position in a log file? Just write to it and have it if do its spill-over.

Comment: Well, I absolutely need a way to move the file if it is too large and since I do not understand the code you have written, I cannot modify it to do exactly what I need so I am resorting to getting the filesize this way and then creating a new stream if it exceeds.

Comment: @Milo: I updated with a bit explanation: I'd think the approach is to have the stream buffer just count the characters and deal with changing files. The logging can then be entirely oblivious of how the data is actually written.